# Unable to run job in quartz getting exception as Illegal access

Tags: java, oracle, quartz-scheduler, netbeans-7

I'm getting following exception

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.TriggerPersistenceDelegate$TriggerPropertyBundle.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.CronTriggerPersistenceDelegate.loadExtendedTriggerProperties(CronTriggerPersistenceDelegate.java:89)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1819)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1531)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2808)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2759)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2757)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3787)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272)

Exception in thread "MyScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/TriggerPersistenceDelegate$TriggerPropertyBundle
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.CronTriggerPersistenceDelegate.loadExtendedTriggerProperties(CronTriggerPersistenceDelegate.java:89)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1819)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1531)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2808)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2759)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2757)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3787)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.TriggerPersistenceDelegate$TriggerPropertyBundle
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 9 more
```

What could be the possible reason for this error? Help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

This the cause

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.TriggerPersistenceDelegate$TriggerPropertyBundle
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
```

Make sure you have the necessary quartz jars in your classphath

Comment: It is there. I'm using `quartz-2.2.1.jar` and It's available in my library folder

Answer (score 0):

The main Quartz library required is `quartz-all-xxx.jar` to use any of Quartz features.

Comment: downloaded `quartz-all-1.6.1.jar` and checking.